# SOAP and REST api - both does keep state

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I am reading about REST api, one of the key point is that it is state less. So my question is, SOAP is also state less.

When you make a call to SOAP api, its not like synchronize connection to database.

if SOAP is also stateless, then what point of highlighting in REST design.

There must something, which I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the reason it is highlighted in REST design is because REST is more of an architectural style that follows a set of constraints and it is commonly associated to the HTTP protocol.  The HTTP protocol is sateless and it is the uniform interface that virtually all REST APIs follow.

SOAP on the other hand is a protocol.  It does not define that it be stateless although because it too leverages message transmission over HTTP that it is usually a good practice to treat SOAP APIs stateless.  So I think to say or assume that SOAP is stateless is a mistake because depending on the framework it could be stateful